# 'The view dashboard.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.' when using POST request of specific variable

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to build a simple view which allows user to change their avatar using form submission. Rendering the view before the POST request works just fine however when a user submits a new image file through form submission I got the following error:

```
Value Error at /
The view dashboard.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

The following is a snippet from my `view.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'imagefile' in request.POST:
            form = forms.AvatarUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                image = request.FILES['image']
                request.user.avatar = image
                request.user.save()
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = forms.AvatarUpdate()
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {"this_page": "home", "form": form})
```

While the `forms.py` is as follow:

```
class AvatarUpdate(forms.Form):
    imagefile = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'name': "imagefile"}), label="Change user avatar")
```

My intention here is that the model would only be saved only if the POST request contains the variable `imagefile`. How should I go about fixing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've made this work, it seems the variable name of the input is part of the `request.FILES` not `request.POST`. So overall the `view.py` would be like this:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def index(request):
    form = forms.AvatarUpdate()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AvatarUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if 'imagefile' in request.FILES:
            if form.is_valid():
                image = request.FILES['imagefile']
                request.user.avatar = image
                request.user.save()
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {"this_page": "home", "form": form})
```

Thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Not all of your if statements return an HttpResponse. If you want to keep the same logic, you would need to put an else with an HttpResponse and you can't just put the last return outside else statement, because your form variable will not be recognised.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'imagefile' in request.POST:
            form = forms.AvatarUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                image = request.FILES['image']
                request.user.avatar = image
                request.user.save()
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return render(...)
        else:
            return render(...)
    else:
        form = forms.AvatarUpdate()
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {"this_page": "home", "form": form})
```

Or you can define a default form value:

```
def index(request):
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'imagefile' in request.POST:
            form = forms.AvatarUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                image = request.FILES['image']
                request.user.avatar = image
                request.user.save()
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = forms.AvatarUpdate()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {"this_page": "home", "form": form})
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is that `imagefile` is not recognized as a variable within the `request.POST`